# Android - Default option in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can i set a default option in a spinner?

I filled 3 spinners with differents querys, and maybe i just want to use 2 of that spinners, not the 3.  So always is a value set in the spinner.   How can i avoid a value? Cause maybe if a fill an array i can set a default option in position 0, but im filling spinners with querys.

I know spinners are made to have a value, so maybe i could put them a default value so in the onitemclicklistener i can avoid using that spinner with an   if (valuespinnerselected = "Default" )   dont to anything

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a label and a value for each index of the `Spinner`.

Think that the value `-1` is the default value that you want to ignore. That way, i think that this piece of code can help you:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    SpinnerItem item1 = new SpinnerItem();
    item1.setText("Default Query");
    item1.setValue(-1);
    SpinnerItem item2 = new SpinnerItem();
    item2.setText("Query1");
    item2.setValue(10);
    SpinnerItem item3 = new SpinnerItem();
    item3.setText("Query 2");
    item3.setValue(20);
    SpinnerItem[] data = new SpinnerItem[3];
    data[0] = item1;
    data[1] = item2;
    data[2] = item3;
    ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where SpinnerItem is the class:

```
public class SpinnerItem {

    String text;
    Integer value;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

After that, you can get the selected item and see his value:

```
    SpinnerItem item = (SpinnerItem) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    if(item.getValue() == -1){
        //do Something.
    }
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest would be to put a default item like you mentioned. It could be "Please select".